# Get the first value of a column for a group, and the last value of a different column using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

```
apt   week     startday       endday
10    1        07.03.2023     07.07.2023
10    2        07.10.2023     07.15.2023
10    3        07.17.2023     07.22.2023
10    4        07.24.2023     07.25.2023
15    3        05.05.2023     05.10.2023
15    4        05.12.2023     05.18.2023
25    1        09.12.2023     09.15.2023
25    2        09.17.2023     09.19.2023
```

i am trying to accomplish in here same apt first week and last weeks combine start day and endday values in one column. so the result should be like this

```
   apt       startday      endday
    10       07.03.2023    07.25.2023
    15       05.05.2023    05.18.2023
    25       09.12.2023    09.19.2023
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can just use `min()` and `max()` functions like this:

```
select apt
     , min(startday)
     , max(endday)
 group by apt;
```

But you should specify which RDBMS you're using.